# Linting in Visual Studio Code not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have been using VSC (Version 1.19.1 for Mac) including the official Python extension (0.9.1) for a couple of month now. As I left most of the configuration unchanged, I have been using Pylint for linting.

Until a couple of weeks ago everything was fine, now linting doesn't work anymore.

An example would be:

```python
def test(x):
return x
```

Here I would normally get an indention error shown by Pylint which doesn't happen anymore.

I have re-installed the Python extension and then re-installed Visual Studio Code, nothing worked. Can anyone help me?

I run MacOS 10.13.1, Python 3.6. and Pylint 1.8.1. My user settings for VSC are:

```
"editor.rulers": [
99
],
"files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false
```

Comment: It works for me. Can you verify that you have selected your Python interpreter and that Pylint is installed for that interpreter? Also make sure you are not running version 0.9.1 of the extension (the latest is 2018.1.0). Otherwise you can always specify the full path to `pylint` (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)

Comment: @brett I am running version 2018.1.0 of the extension. Now I have explicitly selected Python as interpreter and pylint is working for the given example. However, it doesn't raise a problem for other like duplicate whitespaces, missing whitespaces or lines that are too long. I just tested pep8 as linter and that works for the cases just mentioned.

Comment: Ah, that's because in the `.2018.1.0` release we switched to default linter rules for Pylint which ignore all stylistic errors: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2018/02/01/python-in-visual-studio-code-jan-2018-release/ .